# Test Class Will Not Return Value from Method

Tags: apex, unit-test

Below is my class and test class:

```
public class AcaProcess{ 

    public static Decimal retcumgrades = 0;

    public All_In__c AcaCalc( Id applicationId, String applicationType, Id contactId, All_In__c allInvar) {
        //Retrieve the value of the algorithms
        Double naGp = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OS MT', 'MULT FACTOR' ) ;      
        Double naMa = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OS MT', 'MATH FACTOR' ) ;  
        Double naNm = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OS MT', 'NUM COURSES' ) ;              
        Double ogGp = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OG GNO SCORES', 'OG GNO SCORES' ) ;        
        Double OgPa = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OG GPA', 'OG GPA' ) ;                              

        Decimal cumulGrades   = 0; 
        Decimal AcaScore = 0;  
        String  rGrade;        
        Decimal hVerb    = 0;  
        Decimal hMath      = 0;  


        rGrade = GetGrade(applicationId);

        Contact gscores = [SELECT  Math__c, Verbal__c
                           FROM    Contact
                           WHERE   Id = :contactId limit 1];

        hVerb = gscores.Verbal__c; 

        hMath   = gscores.Math__c; 

        List<Past_Study__c> curstuWithAbc = new List<Past_Study__c>();
        curstuWithAbc = [SELECT Id, Grade_Received__c, Honor_Grade__c 
                         FROM   Past_Study__c 
                         WHERE  Grade_Received__c IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
                         AND    Application__c = :applicationId];

        //Records to process
        if (curstuWithAbc.size() > 0) {

            //Call method to return the Cumulative Grades
            cumulGrades = GetCumulativeGrade(applicationId,curstuWithAbc); 

            //Get Math/Verbal scores from and check if 0 or null
            if ( (hVerb == 0) || (hVerb == null) || (hMath == 0) || (hMath == null) ) {

                //Score is set to 0 if if Verbal and/or Math Scores
                //are null or 0 if Initial Program
                AcaScore = 0;

                //If Other Program the calculation is different
                if (applicationType == 'Other Program') {
                    AcaScore = (cumulGrades / curstuWithAbc.size()) * ogGp; 
                } 

                allInvar.All_Math__c   = hMath;
                allInvar.All_Verbal__c = hVerb;
                allInvar.All_AcaScore__c    = AcaScore;
                return allInvar;  
            }

            if (applicationType == 'Initial Program') {
                    Double hMathScoreCalc = (hMath * naMa);
                    AcaScore = ((cumulGrades / curstuWithAbc.size()) * naGp) + hMathScoreCalc + hVerb ; 
                //Calculate Academic Score for Other Program
            } else if (applicationType == 'Other Program') {
                    Double hVerbScoreCalc = GetMathVerbrGrade(rGrade, 'Verbal', hMath, hVerb); 
                    Double hMathScoreCalc   = GetMathVerbrGrade(rGrade, 'Math', hMath, hVerb); 
                    AcaScore = hVerbScoreCalc + hMathScoreCalc + ((cumulGrades / curstuWithAbc.size()) * OgPa);
            }

            allInvar.All_Math__c   = hMath;
            allInvar.All_Verbal__c = hVerb;
            allInvar.All_AcaScore__c    = AcaScore;
        } else {
                //No records to process
                allInvar.All_Math__c   = hMath;
                allInvar.All_Verbal__c = hVerb;
                allInvar.All_AcaScore__c    = 0;
        } 

        return allInvar;
     }    

    public Decimal GetCumulativeGrade(Id applicationId, List<Past_Study__c> curstuWithAbc) {

        retcumgrades = 0;

        for (Past_Study__c acumloop : curstuWithAbc) {
            if (acumloop.Grade_Received__c == 'A') {
                retcumgrades= (retcumgrades + 3);
            } else if (acumloop.Grade_Received__c == 'B') {
                retcumgrades = (retcumgrades + 2);
            } else if (acumloop.Grade_Received__c == 'C') {
                retcumgrades = (retcumgrades + 1);
            }

            //Check if this is an honors course
            if (acumloop.Honor_Grade__c == 'Yes') {
                retcumgrades = (retcumgrades + 1);
            } 
        }
        return retcumgrades;
    } 

    public Double GetMathVerbrGrade(string vrGrade, String wgtType, Decimal ghMath, Decimal ghVerb) {
        Double retcalc = 0;
        if (wgtType == 'Math') {
            if (vrGrade == '8') {
                Double vMath8 = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OGMATH8', 'OGMATH8' ) ;
                retcalc = (ghMath * vMath8);
            } else if (vrGrade == '9') {
                Double vMath9 = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OGMATH8', 'OGMATH8' ) ;
                retcalc = (ghMath * vMath9);
            }    
        } else if (wgtType == 'Verbal') {
            if (vrGrade == '8') {
                Double vVerbal8 = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OGVERB8', 'OGVERB8' ) ;
                retcalc = (ghVerb * vVerbal8);
            } else if (vrGrade == '9') {
                Double vVerbal9 = AlgoMDT.getValue( 'OGVERB9', 'OVERB9' ) ;
                retcalc = (ghVerb * vVerbal9);
            }   
        } 
        return retcalc;
    }  

    //Retrive and return grade
    public String GetGrade(Id applicationid) {
        Id getAppFromCust = applicationid;
        String retrisegrade; 
        retrisegrade = [SELECT Grade_Level__c
                        FROM   S_Appl__c 
                        WHERE  id = :getAppFromCust limit 1][0].Grade_Level__c; 
        return retrisegrade;                  
    }

    //Retrive and return High Verbal
    public Decimal GethVerb(Id applicationid) {
        Id getAppFromCust  = applicationid;
        Decimal rethverbal = 0; 
        rethverbal = [SELECT All_Verbal__c
                      FROM   All_In__c 
                      WHERE  id = :getAppFromCust limit 1][0].All_In__c; 
        return rethverbal;                  
    }

    //Retrive and return High Math
    public Decimal GethMath(Id applicationid) {
        Id getAppFromCust = applicationid;
        Decimal rethmath = 0; 
        rethmath = [SELECT All_Math__c
                    FROM   All_In__c 
                    WHERE  id = :getAppFromCust limit 1][0].All_In__c; 
        return rethmath;                  
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class AcaProcess_Test {    
    @isTest static void TestAcaCalc() {
          //Test.startTest();

          //Can be set below according to testing or comment out if want a default setting
          String  appType;      //Other Program
          Integer acadScore;    //Set it according to testing: 716 
          String  risingGrade;  //Set it according to testing: '8'


          //Create new Contact record; initialize required field(s), then insert 
          Contact Con        = new Contact();
          Con.FirstName      = 'Angela';
          Con.LastName       = 'Wright';
          //

          Insert Con ;

          System.debug(Con.id);

          Test.startTest();
          //Set High Scores for Contact
          Con.Verbal__c   = 500;
          Con.Math__c = 600;

          System.debug('Verbal = ' + Con.Verbal__c );
          System.debug('Math = '   + Con.Math__c );

          //Initialize other fields for created Contact
          String ContactID   = Con.id;

          System.debug('ContactID = ' + ContactID );

          //Create new Application record; initialize required field(s), then insert
          S_Application__c App      = new S_Application__c();
          App.Contact__c            = ContactID;
          Insert App;

          System.debug(App.id);

          //Initialize other fields for created Application
          App.Application_Type__c = 'Initial Program';
          App.Grade_Level__c      = '8';
          App.extraPoints__c      =  50;
          String AppID            = App.id;

          appType     = App.Application_Type__c;
          risingGrade = App.Grade_Level__c;
          extraPoints = App.extraPoints__c;


          //Get Record Id Type   
          Id recTypeId; 
          if (appType == 'Initial Program') {
                System.debug('IN Initial Program');
                recTypeId = [SELECT Id, name 
                             FROM   RecordType 
                             WHERE  name        = 'Initial Program' 
                             AND    SObjectType = 'All_In__c' limit 1].Id;
          } else if (appType == 'Other Program') {
                System.debug('IN Other Program');
                recTypeId = [SELECT Id, name 
                             FROM   RecordType 
                             WHERE  name        = 'Other Program' 
                             AND    SObjectType = 'All_In__c' limit 1].Id;
          } else {
                System.debug('There is a problem getting the Report Type ID');
          }

          System.debug('Record Type ID: ' + recTypeId);       

          All_In__c allInvar = new All_In__c(RecordTypeId = recTypeId);                                 //For non-Existing All In record per Application

          AcaProcess x      = new AcaProcess();

          // Create or Update All In record and AcaScore.  
          All_In__c acadmult  = x.AcaCalc( AppID, appType, ContactID, allInvar);   
          System.debug('acadmult: ' + acadmult);

          //Test that the All In record was correctly created or updated
          System.assertEquals(1750 , acadmult.All_AcaScore__c , 'Aca Score Not Right'); 
          Test.stopTest();
        }
}
```

---

The problem is while running the test class a `null` value is returned from the the `GetGrade` Method. I put in a `system.debug` and application id was passed correctly.

It seem to not like the Select Statement. There should be a grade since I assigned it in the Application I created. Also, I noticed that when other methods (`GetHMath` & `GetHVerb`) in the class were called a `null` was returned if Select was in the method.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 8):

Consider removing the `seeAllData=true` annotation, since you do not appear to need it and use of this annotation without a specific (and rare) reason for requiring it is very bad practice. Doing so makes your unit tests fragile due to exposure to the full and changing breadth of your org's production data.

---

Your unit test populates the `Grade_Level__c` field:

```
  App.Grade_Level__c      = '8';
```

but fails to perform `update` DML to persist this change.

Your `GetGrade()` method then returns `null` from this query:

```
    retrisegrade = [SELECT Grade_Level__c
                    FROM   S_Appl__c 
                    WHERE  id = :getAppFromCust limit 1][0].Grade_Level__c;
```

because the field is in fact `null` in the database. `update` the record to allow this method to see it.